# Is it possible to see if someone used Private Browsing in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, private-browsing

I guess I would not be able to see what was done, but I would like to know if it was used.

This is a one time case and I have not done any logging and don't expect to have to look this up any time in the future, but right now it would be nice to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you could, it wouldn't be very private now would it?

If you're clever with matching up Flash Cookies with browsing history you possibly could deduce that someone cleared some history at some time, but that's about it without some heavy process and/or network logging.